# Getting values from various Labels and doing simple calculation

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to program a simple app in Xcode using Swift.

I have two labels which contain INT values which are incremented up/down by the user using Steppers as per below:

> class ViewController: UIViewController {
>
> ```
> @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
> @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
> @IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
>
>      valueLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
> }
>
>       @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel2: UILabel!
> @IBOutlet weak var stepper2: UIStepper!
> @IBAction func stepperValueChanged2(sender: UIStepper) {
>
>      valueLabel2.text = Int(sender.value).description
> }
> ```

I want to then have another Label (label3) which takes the INTs from label1 & label2 and divides them.

So for example if the user has Label1 as '5' and label2 as '10' I want label3 to display '0.5'.

Is there an easy way that I can do this?

As I'm sure you can tell, I'm really new to iOS development so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is a simple program you should still use best practice and adopt a model-view-controller design.  Your model (data) should be separate from view (in essence the way the data is displayed). In a more 'serious' application the model would typically be a separate class, but in this case you can use local properties.

Storing data in Int properties also means you won't have to convert back from strings when you want to perform calculations.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!      
@IBOutlet weak var valueLabel2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper2: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var valueLabel3: UILabel!

var value1=0;
var value2=0;

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {

     self.value1=Int(sender.value);
     self.valueLabel1.text="\(self.value1)";
     self.updateResult();
}


@IBAction func stepperValueChanged2(sender: UIStepper) {

     self.value2=Int(sender.value);
     self.valueLabel1.text="\(self.value1)";
     self.updateResult();
}

func updateResult {
     if (self.value2 != 0) {
         var result=Float(self.value1)/Float(self.value2)
         self.valueLabel3.text="\(result)"
     } else {
         self.valueLabel3.text="Can't divide by 0"
     }
}
}
```